# Altbeacon: disable Foreground mode and Terminate app from Notifcation AddAction

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

I'm recently trying to build an application that uses AltBeacon Library.

The problem that I'm facing right now is this: I created an Application class in this way:

```
    beaconManager = beaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));


    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));


    beaconManager.setRegionStatePersistenceEnabled(false);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);



    builder.setBadgeIconType(Notification.BADGE_ICON_NONE);


    Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ButtonReceiver.class);
    buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId",NOTIFICATION_ID);

    PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent,0);


    builder.addAction(R.drawable.stop,"Termina Rilevamento.", btPendingIntent);



    builder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mygreen));

    builder.setContentIntent(btPendingIntent);

    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);


    builder.setContentTitle("Rilevazione autenticazione in corso.");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);



    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification Channel ID",
                "My Notification Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("My Notification Channel Description");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());



    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);


    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);

    Region region = new Region("Region iniziale",null,Identifier.parse("789"),null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
```

Where the Button on the notification points to a BroadCastReceiver class that is ButtonReceiver. 
In button receiver I want to execute the action of disabling the foreground service and to close out the application. 
I do it in this way:

```
    int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(notificationId);

    AndroidWalkEnrollmentApplication prova = new AndroidWalkEnrollmentApplication();
    prova.disableMonitoring();
```

inside the onReceive() method.

So the problem is this: in disableMonitoring() I follow the example of the Android-Beacon-Reference and so to disable the foreground scanning I do:
bootstrap.disable() and bootstrap=null. The problem is that it seems to not work. When I press the button inside the notification the foreground mode it's note disabled. I also tried to execute Beaconmanager.disableForegroundService() but it doesn't actually disable it.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the 2.15.2 release of the library that prevents stopping the foreground service properly.  But good news: this has been very recently fixed in this experimental release:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/releases/tag/more-reliable-service-stop2

You may use the above fix immediatly by following the integration instructions on the release.  This change will also be included in a formal release in 1-2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I will try this solution out!

Comment: Hey! I saw that the change was included in the formal release! What should the command to stop the foreground scanning and to close the application be, to include it in the notification addAction? I'd like to do it in an elegant way that doesn't crash it.

Comment: The formal release is not yet out as of this post, but to stop the foreground service you simply call regionBootstrap.diaable(); or beaconManager.unbind(this);  depending on which class you used to start the sccanning.

Comment: I implemented these methods but I keep getting my app restarted after like 5 minutes? Do you have any idea of what it could be?

Comment: Please open a new question with the specifics.  Comments do not give room to answer.

Comment: Ok I followed you advice! This is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458978/altbeacon-app-restarts-after-some-minutes